# Best way to figure out if component is an instance of functional component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-component, react-functional-component

For a component I'm building I'm recursively looping over its child components using `React.Children.map` to make modifications to their props. The basic structure is like this:

```js
// main component
const Main = ({ children }) => recursivelyModifyChildProps(children);

// recursive function
function recursivelyModifyChildProps(children) {
  return React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
    // if no valid react element, just return it
    if (!React.isValidElement(child)) {
      return child;
    }

    // check if child isn't a `<Main/>` component
    // not sure about this check
    if (typeof child.type !== 'string' && child.type.name === 'Main') {
      return child;
    }

    const { children, ...restProps } = child.props;

    // do stuff to create new props
    const newProps = { foo: 'bar' };

    // return new element with modified props
    return React.createElement(
      child.type,
      {
        ...restProps,
        ...newProps,
        children: recursivelyModifyChildProps(children)
      }
    );

  });
}
```

Children of `Main` will have their props modified via `recursivelyModifyChildProps` and their children will have their props modified, etc. I want to do this unless the child component is an instance of the `Main` component, in that case it should be returned unmodified. Currently I'm doing this via `child.type.name`, and this does work. However, this implementation is very bug prone I believe, since everyone could call their component "Main". What is the best (or at least a better) way to figure out that a component is an instance a particular (functional) component, or an instance of itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can validate it by comparing the `child.type` to `Main` instance which is unique.

```
if (child.type === Main) {
  return undefined;
}
```

[image: Edit Q-58851178-childType]

---

A full example of modifying all `Main` children with skipping the `Main` instance.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const Main = ({ children }) => recursivelyModifyChildProps(children);

function recursivelyModifyChildProps(children) {
  return React.Children.map(children, child => {
    if (!React.isValidElement(child)) {
      return child;
    }

    if (child.type === Main) {
      return undefined;
    }

    const { children, ...restProps } = child.props;
    const newProps = { foo: 'bar' };

    return React.createElement(child.type, {
      ...restProps,
      ...newProps,
      children: recursivelyModifyChildProps(children)
    });
  });
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Main>
//       v Main is skipped
      <Main />
      <div>Hello</div>
    </Main>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```